# React Multiple maps and key storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Have a multiple array, to which an option set is created, which works fine

```
  const groups1 = OrgServices.reduce((all, cur) => ((all[cur.grouptype] ??= []).push(...cur.servicetype), all), {});
     const output1 = Object.entries(groups1).map(([k, v]) => ({ grouptype: k, servicetype: v }));
```

```
                            <select id="type" name={'type'} 
                            onChange={(e: any) => {setTypeOfService(e.target.value)}} 
                            className="block w-full rounded-md border-0 py-1.5 text-gray-900 shadow-sm ring-1 ring-inset ring-gray-300 placeholder:text-gray-400 focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-600 sm:text-sm sm:leading-6"
                > 
                <option>Select Service Type:</option>
                {output1.map((service) => {return service.servicetype.map(element => {return ( <option key={service.id}> {service.grouptype} - {element.name} </option>)})})}

                
                </select>
```

But i also want to use other values in the element section for other parts of the post that happens after.

So the element has multiple values name, price, type etc but i want to pass them in my create on button press not just the value of element.name

Comment: refactored hopefully that helps

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Also format your code properly to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

Listen, pass the element and group type as props

```
{output1.map((service) => {return service.servicetype.map(element => {return ( <Option groupType={service.groupType} element={element} />)})}
```

Access your props like

```
function Option(props) {

return (
<div>
  <p>{props.groupType}<p/>
  <p>{props.element.name}<p/>
</div>
);

}

export default Option
```

Comment: the <option> is in a select box its not a component

Comment: `Now it is Dan`